# Passing data on button press

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button, android-dialog

I have sort of a file manager. It displays files in a `ListView`. Each of those `ListView`s has a custom footer - a button, which is defined in a xml file. Pressing a button allows user to chose a file from the "downloads" directory and copy it to the folder where the button was pressed. This is implemented through the `AlertDialog`. So by clicking the option from the dialog I get a path of a file that should be copied.

Now, how do I get the location from which my button was pressed? Can I somehow pack some sort of data in my button on its creation so that later when it is pressed I could identify its initial location?

Comment: Pressing a button allows user to chose a file from the "downloads" directory and copy it to the folder where the button was pressed

Do you have a single button or two buttons?

Comment: one button. When you press it - an AlertDialog lists all the files from the downloads folder. When you click on one of those files it is copied to a folder where you pressed the button.

Comment: you want this file (may be data/path/name that is clicked on the listview) to the shown on previous place when you have a button ?

Comment: Dear Sharath, that is correct. But I have already resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to achieve that. you can create a separate OnClickListener for each button as JaLoveAst1k proposes. you could also add some information to the buttons's tag (setTag()) and get it back in the onClick() function. Yet another way would be to have a `Hashtable<Button, String>` where you store your string informaton relative to the Button.

Comment: Actually I have implemented it slightly differently, but I believe I might go back to your solution later on (:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
protected class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String text;

    public CustomListener(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

            ...
}
```

And set this listener to button, in constructor give data.